# Weinstein's neighborhood theorem for exact symplectic manifolds

Tags: sg.symplectic-geometry

Let $(M, \omega)$ be a symplectic manifold and $L\subset M$ a Lagrangian submanifold. The Lagrangian Neighborhood Theorem says that there exists a neighborhood $U$ of $L$ in $M$ and a symplectomorphism $F\colon U\to V\subset T^\ast L$ mapping $L$ identically to the zero-section of $T^\ast L$.

Given an exact symplectic manifold $(M, \theta)$ (i.e., $\omega = \mathrm{d} \theta$ is a symplectic form on $M$) and a Lagrangian submanifold $L\subset M$, is it possible to construct a symplectomorphism $F$ as above which also satisfies $F^\ast \theta_L = \theta$, for $\theta_L$ the canonical one-form of the cotangent bundle $T^\ast L$?